# Why does rpmfusion recommend the nogpgcheck switch?

Tags: centos, rhel, security, rpm, gpg

See the commandline RHEL/CentOS section at https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/

Doesn't this `--nogpgcheck` switch allow for tampering to happen unnoticed?

Answer (score 0):

That's a a step to break the initial chicken and egg trust problem by the packaging system.

There is no trust by the packaging system (`yum`/`rpm`) in the new repository since, being new, it's not initially known. So the first step would be to tell the system to (cryptographically) trust this new repository. That's done by signing packages (or on different systems, package releases).

Some methods give a gpg key in a separate web page or keyserver to add to the system's trust (eg: [`rpm --import`](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1976693) (really [`rpmkeys --import`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f27/system-administrators-guide/RPM/#s1-check-rpm-sig)), or an equivalent for `apt`/`dpkg`: [`apt-key add`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f27/system-administrators-guide/RPM/#s1-check-rpm-sig)) and then configure the repository with the correct file that includes mostly the URL to download and some settings (like the... `gpgcheck=1` parameter).

An other method is to put this key directly in a package and let the package add the key and repository settings: that's what's done here, the package `rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm` has inside only a few files:

```
# rpm -qlp rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm 
warning: rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID f5cf6c1e: NOKEY
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-el-7
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
```

Those files are the key and the new repositories configurations, and they do include `gpgcheck=1`. Note that until installed, the system doesn't trust the package (hence the warning above with `NOKEY`). Once installed, the key is now trusted, and every further action will check package signatures with this added key.

So how can it be trusted? There's still the trust provided by the use of `https://` in `https://download1.rpmfusion.org/` when it was downloaded: it should guarantee that the download site owned by rpmfusion is in control of this package and it can be downloaded securely without being tampered with.

It's not the exactly the same kind of trust, because only the site is trusted to be what it claims, not the package. Since you're downloading software from rpmfusion anyway, this implies you're trusting them enough to download and install packages from them. This package should never be downloaded the first time outside of `*.rpmfusion.org` to initially add the repository (ie when installing with `--nogpgcheck`), or you'd now have to trust the mirror to actually provide the same package and not an other with the same name with for example additional keys or worse.

Anyway, with the former method, you still had to read instructions on how to add a key and download a package anyway, so you still had to initially trust those instructions. That's what I call chicken and egg: you have to start trusting somewhere.

Once this initial trust happened, everything else is "taken care of" securely. Even if a new key has to be provided, this will be done with an update of `rpmfusion-free-release` with (a) replacement key(s) inside, and it would stay secure even if downloaded from a mirror and/or without `https://`. That's actually the case for this repository: it's using mirrors and probably plain http. You shouldn't ever need again the `--nogpgcheck`.

Comment: Note that you can import the gpg keys trusted way: `dnf install distribution-gpg-keys && rpm --import /usr/share/distribution-gpg-keys/rpmfusion/*` But I agree that rpmfusion guys do not know about this, so they recommend this way.